# Passing values to function using numpy

Tags: python, function, numpy

Suppose, I have a function that has three inputs prob(x,mu,sig).
With sizes:

```
x = 1 x 3
mu = 1 x 3
sig = 3 x 3
```

Now, I have a dataset X, mean matrix M and std. deviation matrix sigma.
Sizes are:-

```
X : m x 3.
mean :  k x 3. 
sigma :  k x 3 x 3
```

For each value m, I want to pass all values of k in the function prob to calculate my responsibility value.

I can pass the values one by one using for loops.
What would be a better way of doing this in numpy.

The related code for reference:

```
responsibility = np.zeros((X.shape[0],k))
    s = np.zeros(k)
    for i in np.arange(X.shape[0]):
        for j in np.arange(k):
            s[j] = prob(X[i],MU[j],SIGMA[j])
        s = s/s.sum()
        responsibility[i] = s
    responsibility = np.transpose(responsibility)
```

Comment: please provide example code where you show how you are implementing it at present

Comment: Just added the code section. Please check

Answer (score 0):

If using a single for loop is acceptable then you can probably use the following,

```
import itertools

sigma.shape = k, 9
zipped_array = np.array(list(zip(mean, sigma)))
all_possible_combo = list(itertools.product(X, zipped_array))
list_len = len(all_possible_combo) # = m * k
s = np.zeros(k)
responsibility = np.zeros((X.shape[0],k))
for i in range(list_len):
    X_arow = all_possible_combo[i][0]
    mean_single = all_possible_combo[i][1]
    sigma_single = all_possible_combo[i][2].reshape((3, 3))
    s = prob(X_arow, mean_single, sigma_single)
    s = s/s.sum()
    responsibility[i] = s
responsibility = np.transpose(responsibility)
```

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Doesnot seem to work. For the line: zipped_array = np.array(list(zip(mean, sigma))) get the following error : Could not broadcast from shape (3,3) to 3

Comment: How about now ?

Comment: in line: sigma_single = all_possible_combo[i][2].reshape((3, 3))  ---  Tuple index out of range